# Laravel 5.2: POST request is always returning "405 Method Not Allowed"

Tags: php, api, laravel, post

So I am developing an API with Laravel 5.2 and I'm facing an important issue.

I have a UserController that will manage the users of my app.

This is my routes.php file:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function() {    
   Route::post('user', 'UserController@store');
});
```

And I have my UserController defined like that:

```
class UserController extends Controller {

   public function index() {
       return 'Hello, API';
   }

   public function create(){
   }

   public function store(Request $request) {
       $user = new User;
       $user->email = $request->email;
       $user->password = $request->password;
       $user->fbId = $request->fbId;
       $user->ggId = $request->ggId;
       $user->firstName = $request->firstName;
       $user->lastName = $request->lastName;
       $user->imageUrl = $request->imageUrl;
       $user->country = $request->country;
       $user->mobile = $request->mobile;
       $user->gender = $request->gender;
       $user->client = $request->client;

       $user->save();

       return Response::json(array(
           'error' => false,
           'userId' => $user->id),
           200
       );
   }

   public function update(Request $request, $id) {
   }
}
```

And this is the output of `php artisan route:list`

```
+--------+--------+-------------+------+-------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method | URI         | Name | Action                                    | Middleware |
+--------+--------+-------------+------+-------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | POST   | api/v1/user |      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@store | web        |
+--------+--------+-------------+------+-------------------------------------------+------------+
```

I'm using Postman to test my POST requests. 
Every time I make a POST request to /api/v1/user, I get a "405 Method Not Allowed" error.

Did I miss anything?

Is there anything I should do to fix this issue?

Comment: Why are you using `Route::resource('user', 'UserController');` and not `Route::post('user','userController@store')` ?

Comment: @Kisaragi - If I use `Route::post('user', 'UserController@store')` I get "405 Method Not Allowed".

Comment: It's call index method everytime. Please just comment index method one time and see the result. May be it works!!

Comment: @HirenGohel - I don't think it should call index() everytime. Anw, if I do this, I get a "500 Internal Server Error".

Comment: Ok...I am new to laravel.:)  You use $request->user()->create([]); Do you sets eloquent relationship alright?? @Joseph

Comment: @HirenGohel - Yes sure. The problem is not from the content of the function. Even If I leave it empty, It doesn't get called.

Comment: What does your .htaccess look like?

Comment: @patricus - 
`Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`

Comment: @JosephELKHOURY may be its route caching? Try `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @GONG - I tried it, but didn't work :(

Comment: @JosephELKHOURY can you provide listing of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Can you try removing your "before" filter on the group, just to see if it works? I'm assuming you're not authorized when coming from Postman.

Comment: @patricus - I did so and I'm still facing the same problem. I finally used the `Route::post('user','userController@store')` and now I'm always getting the Method Not Allowed error.

Comment: @GONG - I edited my post and listed all the routes.

Comment: Try setting the route to `get` and hitting it with your browser.  Recently when I try to communicate with Laravel using Postman, I'm not able to actually get it to use `POST`, it always uses `GET` for some reason.

Comment: @user3158900 - With `get` it works perfectly. The problem is with `post` :( And the problem is not from Postman because If I check the logs of my apache server, I get this `POST /api/v1/user HTTP/1.1" 405 2497`

Answer (score 47):

I have same problem with you which are I already set in my POST route for example "/api/v1/user",
 
and when I try to connect using POSTMAN (application to test API) , it return 405-Method Not Allowed,

and then i realize the url i was sent is using '**http**' and after i change it to '**https**' (with the 's' at the back) 
then my API working like normal !

normally if we interact with different server , we must use '**https**' 
but if your application at the same server , 
 it's okay to use '**http**'


The real reason for my case is any interaction with any different server must use '**https**' (This is the setup on my server)

Comment: Omfg... Thanks man. Something as simple as that made me waste 1 hour

Comment: Dude, you're a hero! So much time wasted for nothing! It worked fine in curl, because CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=true. Totally forget about it in Postman!

Comment: brooooo, i just realized that im using ssl on the server, 2 days wasted for this. how stupid i am hahahaha

Answer (score 8):

You need to separate your routes because all the users trying to get to your routes need a open session (logged in)

Try this

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function() {

    Route::post('/','UserController@store');

    Route::get('/', 'UserController@index');

    Route::group(array('before' => 'auth.basic'), function() {

        Route::post('{user}', 'UserController@update');

    });
});
```

Your authorized users routes should be in the second group

And your 405 Method not Allowed is `$user->id` change it for `$request->user()->id`

Comment: Yes you are totally right, but I just started the project and I still didn't separate endpoints that needs authentication from those that don't need it.

Comment: you might want start using the middleware `Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () { ... });`

Comment: I will :) Thank you

Comment: @JosephELKHOURY 405 Method not Allowed is `$user->id` change it for `$request->user()->id`

Comment: @JosephELKHOURY remember to save `$user->save()`

Comment: @JosephELKHOURY did you write your used namespace? like `use App\User;` and `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Answer (score 5):

### Missing CSRF token

I had the same issue on Laravel 5.8 when creating `web-hooks` routes.

These routes use the **web middleware** and because of that, the **VerifyCsrfToken route middleware group** is also included. (Reference `app/Http/Kernel.php`)

Because my POST request doesn't include a **CSRF token** we get this strange behaviour.

### Add CSRF exception

To fix this, I needed to **[add an exception](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris) to the VerifyCsrfToken middleware** for the web-hooks routes. (Reference `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`)

```
/**
 * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $except = [
    'web-hooks/*'
];
```

### Use API middleware

The above solution is for when the web middleware is used. However if you are creating API routes, it is better to use the api middleware instead because no CSRF verification is used in this middleware. (Reference `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`)

```
    Route::prefix('api')
        ->middleware('api')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing to https will cause it to work. At least, that is what I have experienced. Using POSTman with http always has this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Faced something similar before, after debugging turns out it's Postman problem and nothing related to the code!

So open your terminal and try making the same request with curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -F "email=test@test.com" -F "password=secret" -F "firstName=Mahmoud"  -F "lastName=Zalt" ....... "http://your-domain.com/api/v1/user"
```

If this worked means you have to change few settings with Postman itself.
Really can't remember what I did to it! But it's something as simple as changing some default headers or removing the Authorization type...

Comment: mmm try checking your HTTP Middleware's or enabling CORS

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have "Accept":"application/json" in your header.

E.G
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: Thunder Client (https://www.thunderclient.io)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone I had this exact same problem; for some reason a combination of things fixed it.

1. The obvious point was that it would return a `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161` this was due to me not sending my "api_token" in my post request.
2. For some reason (I don't know if this made a difference) but chaining my middleware worked instead of putting it in the Route:group I did;

   ```
   Route::group(['prefix'=>'api/v1'], function () {
       Route::post('/', 'IndexController@index')->middleware('auth:api');
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be caused by a request body that's too large. In my case, I was accidentally sending an object with many sub-objects that all had many other sub-objects. Pruning my request data solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your request type `GET/POST/PUT/PATCH` in both side 
i.e. **frontend**(`Javascript/Typescript etc...`) as well as **backend**(`Laravel Passport`) it should be same.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didnt add Controller word to controller's name

Answer (score -2):

After long hours of digging and digging, I couldn't find any solution to my problem.

I had to create a new Laravel project from scratch and add everything I had in my old project. To my surprise, everything worked perfectly and I still don't understand why!

Anyways, thanks to all who tried to help on this :) Cheers!

Comment: you should consider switching your answer, to the right answer, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Deleting a Laravel instance and starting from scratch, from all the answers you got, this would be the best answer? I doubt it. Just erase your answer and pick a viable answer.

Comment: None of the answers fixed the issue. I'll definitely not mark them as "correct" answers and mislead users.

Comment: No one suggested you should mark wrong answers, your logic is false. You've picked your own answer that states that "creating a new laravel project" is the answer and that is also, wrong logic. That would be compared to someone having an issue with drive C:/> and you would offer to format it, as a solution.

Comment: Gotta agree with cluster in that this answer does not really answer the question you posted... It doesn't help understand the problem and its proper solution...