# does laravel accept these requests on controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, frameworks

i have the following code on my controller which will generate textboxes corresponding to the increment:

```
public function DoShowSales(Request $request){
    $rules = [       
    'or_number'=>'required',
    'customer_name'=>'required',
    'payment'=>'required',
    ];  
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);
    if($validator->fails()){
        return back()->withErrors($validator);
    }
    else{
    $inc = $request->input('inc');   
    $inc2 = 1;
    for($inc2; $inc2 <= $inc; $inc2++)
    {
        $ix = ($request->input('i_name'.$inc2));
        $ix2 = ($request->input('quan'.$inc2));  
        $ix3 = ($request->input('tot'.$inc2));           
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="orders'.$inc2.'" id="orders'.$inc2.'" class="getOrders" value="'.$ix.'">'; 
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_quan'.$inc2.'" id="item_quan'.$inc2.'" class="getOrders" value="'.$ix2.'">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="price_tot'.$inc2.'" id="price_tot'.$inc2.'" class="getOrders" value="'.$ix3.'">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" id="inc" value="'.$inc.'">';                     
    }          
         return view('show_sales');                    
    }
}
```

which is when the controller above is triggered, will go to this controller which will save the multiple inputs:

```
 public function DoAddSales(Request $request){       
    $inc = $request->input('inc');
    $inc2 = 1;
    $sales = new sales;
   for($inc2; $inc2 <= $inc; $inc2++)
    {                     
        $sales->or = $request->input('or'); 
        $sales->customer_name = $request->input('cus_name'); 
        $sales->item_id = Item::find($request->input('orders'.$inc2))->id;
        $sales->category_id = Category::find($request->input('orders'.$inc2))->id;
        $sales->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $sales->qty = $request->input('item_quan'.$inc2);
        $sales->total = $request->input('total');
        $sales->save();     
    }
    return redirect('use-pos');       
}
```

do eloquent accept these codes? i want to know the way how to store my values to my database and im getting an error on laravel.

show_sales.blade.php

```
<form action = "{{ url('show-sales') }}" method="post">
                   {{ csrf_field() }}
                   <table class="table dynamic_field">                        
                   <label>OR Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="sp_or"></span>
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <br>
                   <br>
                   Sold To:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="sp_name"></span></label>
                   <thead>
                   <th>Items</th>
                   <th>Qty</th>
                   <th>Total</th>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>

                  <!-- empty -->
                  </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <!-- hidden input-->

                  <input type="hidden" id="or" name="or">
                  <input type="hidden" id="cus_name" name="cus_name">
                  <input type="hidden" id="total" name="total">
                  <!-- end of hidden input-->

                  <label>TOTAL:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="sp_tot"></span></label>
                  <br>
                  <label>CUSTOMER CHANGE:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <a href="{{ url('use-pos') }}">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Go Back</button>
                  </a>&nbsp;
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Complete Purchase">
                  </form>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: methodNotAllowed(array('POST'))

Comment: You should never write HTML code in your controller method (you have used hidden fields).

Comment: What is your route setup for ```show-sales```? It should be something like ```Route::post('show-sales'...```

Comment: `Route::post('show-sales','HomeController@DoAddSales');`

Comment: Then method POST is allowed. There must be something else going on that you are not explaining. Try and be a bit more clear

Comment: Check this [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836223/laravel-5-2-post-request-is-always-returning-405-method-not-allowed), hope you get something helpful